# How can I return the first N number of characters ending with a complete word from a dash-delimited string?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need a function that outputs first **N** number of characters in a **dash-delimited** input string.

**Requirements**:

1. If N drops in the middle of a word, include the last word in the output even if total gets more than N
2. If the output ends with "-" AND LEN(output) == N , then include next word

Example: (N = 70)

```
declare @Text varchar(1000) = 'this-is-product-url-prepared-for-better-Google-Search-Engnine-SEO-totalLength-should-be-70-characters'
```

I have already taken the first 70 characters, which results in the following (I remove ending dash - in a separate step not included here):

```
SELECT LEFT(@Text + '-', CHARINDEX('-',@Text, 70))
this-is-product-url-prepared-for-better-Google-Search-Engnine-SEO-tot
```

I need a function that returns the following in this case:

```
this-is-product-url-prepared-for-better-Google-Search-Engnine-SEO-totalLength
```

Any solutions will be appreciated.

Comment: So what have you tried, why didn't it work? "I need" isn't a question; what is it you're asking here?

Comment: Hint: add `-` to the string so it always ends predictably, and `CHARINDEX` has a third parameter.

Comment: `LEFT(@Text,CHARINDEX('-',@Text+'-',70)-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @LukStorms

I achieved this by the following statement:

```
LEFT(@Text,CHARINDEX('-',@Text+'-',70)-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED ANSWER: Fixed your expression**

This will work and is based on what @Lukstroms posted; his does not handle your second requirement (when @N is the position of a hyphen.)

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Text,1,CHARINDEX('-',@Text,@N+1)-1);
```

**PREVIOUS ANSWER:**

Here's how you could do something like this using [ngrams8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) This will handle situations where @N represents the middle of the word or a dash `-`.

```
DECLARE 
  @Text VARCHAR(1000) = 'this-is-product-url-prepared-for-better-Google-Search-Engnine-SEO-totalLength-should-be-70-characters',
  @N    INT           = 70;

SELECT SUBSTRING(@Text,0,MAX(ng.nxt))
FROM 
(
  SELECT ng.position, nxt = LEAD(ng.Position,1) OVER (ORDER BY ng.Position), ng.Token
  FROM   samd.ngrams8k(@Text,1) AS ng
  WHERE  ng.Token = '-'  
) AS ng
WHERE ng.Position <= @N;
```

**FINAL UPDATE (NOTE ABOUT N-GRAMS)**

As Martin correctly mentioned, the N-Grams solution is overly complex but I was in a rush and couldn't fix the OP's original CHARINDEX expression. That said, ngrams8k solution is nasty fast allows a bunch of flexibility.

For example, let's say the requirement included an upper and lower bound parameter; e.g. we needed everything ***between*** the *first* hyphen higher than `@Low` and the *last* hyphen lower than `@High`. This can be handled using a minor tweak to the answer above.

```
DECLARE
  @Text VARCHAR(1000) = 'this-is-product-url-prepared-for-better-Google-Search-Engnine-SEO-totalLength-should-be-70-characters',
  @Low  INT           = 16,
  @high INT           = 70;

SELECT NewString = SUBSTRING(@Text,MIN(ng.position)+1, MAX(ng.nxt)-MIN(ng.position)-1)
FROM 
(
  SELECT ng.position, nxt=LEAD(ng.Position,1) OVER (ORDER BY ng.Position)
  FROM   samd.ngrams8k(@Text,1) AS ng
  WHERE  ng.Token = '-'  
) AS ng
WHERE ng.Position <= @high AND ng.Position > @low;
```

**Returns:**

```
prepared-for-better-Google-Search-Engnine-SEO-totalLength
```

Comment: Seems overly complex compared with LukStorm's answer in a comment.